# Distinguish between text and code in a post

Tags: text, heuristics

I was wondering if there was any acceptable way of doing it. I want to distinguish between code and text in some emails or long posts, in order to highlight the code differently.

I was thinking about something like

```
if(this line and next 10 lines could be code only)
  hightlight them();
```

One of the requirement to consider a line code only would be, for example, the lack of spaces between groups of [a-z0-9] characters (when not between quotes), but there could possibly be many more.

Comment: if it's in a post, wrap the code in `<pre>` or `<code>` tags and use CSS. Read more about [pre](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-PRE) and [code](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-CODE).

Comment: As you can certainly image, I wouldn't go to those lengths if I had control over the posts.